# Configure USB GSM Modem

Tags: 10.10, usb, modem

I want to configure EVDO Usb Modem in Ubuntu 10.10
I insert my usb modem to laptop and check the usb is detected or not using `$sudo lsusb`  and the result is:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 201e:2009
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 14cd:6600 Super Top USB 2.0 IDE DEVICE
```

`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 201e:2009` is my us device. 
and than I execute command `$dmesg | grep -e tty`

```
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[  818.054660] usb 2-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  818.055125] usb 2-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  818.055647] usb 2-1.3: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[  818.330641] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  818.330743] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[  818.330840] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
[ 1054.917473] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 1054.917995] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 1054.918481] usb 2-1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[ 1055.214087] option1 ttyUSB0: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1055.214221] option1 ttyUSB1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[ 1055.214356] option1 ttyUSB2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
```

Why converter disconnected from ttyUSB2 ?

and than I try to execute command `$sudo wvdialconf`

```
sorry, no modem was detected!  Is it in use by another program ?
did you configure it properly with setserials ?
```

I change the same type usb modem from my friend, but I still get error above.

Comment: UbuDSL is for DSL modems. EVDO (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EVDO) is mobile broadband.
Instead, if you are under GNOME/XFCE you could try the NetworkManager through its applet.
There's a "Mobile Broadband" feature which happens to be working 100% of the times with my GSM/UMTS/HSDPA modems.

Comment: I've found the solution. First, I must connecting the USB modem from windows operating system, and disconnect the modem. After that restart the computer, and choose Ubuntu Operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You could give [UbuDSL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubudsl/) a try, though it hasn't been updated in a little while, and I'm not 100% sure if your modem will be supported, but it might just work.

BTW I found a pair of links that might help (though documentation otherwise seems a bit lacking):

1. http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9498429&postcount=5
2. http://ubumodems.blogspot.com/